# Button in UICollectionView's Cell not working

Tags: xcode

I added a button to my collection view, but I cannot press it. I coded it so it would print something to the console as a test, but it still didn't work. The UIButton is connected to the respective class as well.

This is the code:

```
@IBAction func plusTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("presses!")
    }
```

Comment: Bind the action with UIViewController class

Answer (score 0):

Where have you placed this `@IBAction`?

1. Inside your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass
   OR
2. Inside your `UIViewController` subclass

It should be in **#1**

---

Please check if your button allows user interaction.
Check inside storyboard for `User Interaction Enabled` checkbox, it should be checked.
Make sure you are not changing this to `false` from code using `isUserInteractionEnabled` property.

---

Use `View Hierarchy Debugger` to make sure your button is on top of all other subviews at run time and has **non zero**
`width` / `height`.

---

Maybe try disconncting this action from storyboard and reconnecting again? Could be a signature mismatch because of copy paste code.

---

#### UPDATE

In the attached screenshot [image]

I can see two **plus** buttons,

1. one inside the `ProductCollectionViewCell > Content View`
2. other inside the `View Controller > View`, right between **Total Label** & **Navigation Item**.

You should make sure that you connect the first one to `@IBAction` inside the `ProductCollectionViewCell` and NOT the second one.

---

#### UPDATE 2 - For the EDIT in question

In the attached screenshot - we can see that the **plus** button is below other views in the hierarchy inside the `Content View`.
[image]

You can try moving this to be on top of all other views within the `Content View` by dragging along the red-arrow markup so that it is present above `Constraints` and below `Stock Cell`.

This will ensure that no other views are overlapping the button.

As for the `UIButtonLabel` that you are seeing, that is internal `UIKit` class that you can't control and you won't have issues because of that.

---

Comment: Yes, the @IBAction is connected to the UICollectionViewCell. Everything you've mentioned is fine too. I'm not too sure but could this be because my UICollectionViewCell is a cocoa touch class and not a class made on swift file? I used cocoa touch because I read somewhere that I'm supposed to use that for UICollectionView.

Comment: See the UPDATE.

Comment: I just checked, it is connected to the right @IBAction

Comment: Can you use `View Hierarchy Debugger` to examine the frame - width/height of this button at run time? You need to make sure that it is not overlapped by other views and it's user interaction is enabled.

Comment: Could you please see the EDIT

Comment: See UPDATE 2 in the answer.

Comment: I just did what you said, but it still didn't work. I updated the post for clarity.

Comment: Tap on the Button in the left side panel of the `View Hierarchy Debugger`, Inspect it's property on the right side panel - attributes & size inspector. Attributes inspector will tell you whether this has `User Interaction Enabled` or not. Size inspector will tell you whether it's width / height are non-zero.

Comment: User Interaction is Enabled and the width and height are non-zero values as well. I've updated to show screenshots too.

Comment: I also tried doing the same thing with a new button, it shows the pressed animation on the simulator, but the function doesn't run..

Comment: Can you check what are the width/height values for `ProductCollectionViewCell > View` i.e. superview for Button in the `View Hierarchy Debugger`?

Comment: I updated the post to show the screenshot and code

Comment: The **EDIT 4** shows a screenshot from Interface Builder. We need to know it's width/height at run time. So you would need to inspect these in `View Hierarchy Debugger`  as I originally asked in the above comment.

Comment: I edited the **EDIT 4** to show the inspector

Comment: It still shows the `ProductCollectionViewCell` itself. We need to see the details for `ProductCollectionViewCell > View` (that's superview for all the cell UI elements) as originally asked a few comments above.

Comment: I apologize, is **Edit 5** what you meant?

Comment: No, you went one step up in the hierarchy - that's the `UICollectionView` itself that contains all these `ProductCollectionViewCell` instances. We need to know the details by going one step down in the hierarchy - `ProductCollectionViewCell > View`

Comment: Frame looks alright, Can you check if `User Interaction Enabled` is checked for this view?

Comment: It is on for this too

Comment: Go to storyboard, tap on this button inside the cell, right click and share what it shows.

Comment: Added it in **Edit 6**

Comment: Can you update the photo by expanding this info panel in width so we can see the full name of the function? You can do this by using the bottom right \\\ icon within that info panel.

Comment: Disconnect this action from storyboard, adn then again start the drag from touchUpInside slot to the ProductCollectionViewCell, what are the list of options to connect to you see?

Comment: It shows the `addTapped` thing available for connection

Comment: So we have an issue here between `addTapped` & `plusTapped`. Can you share the current code for your `ProductCollectionViewCell` class?

Comment: So addTapped was a an IBAction I made while testing things out a few hours back. I had already deleted that and my code updated in **Edit 8** is the `ProductionCollectionViewCell`

Comment: Can you try disconnecting from storyboard and connecting from Code? You can create an outlet for your button, then call `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`. You can place this inside populate method.

Comment: Here's the link to my project. It would mean a lot if you could help me out with this problem. https://github.com/evanalulu/The-Patisserie

Comment: Seems like the wrong link - it looks like an empty template project. No code related to what we are discussing here.

Comment: I apologize, here's the actual link -> https://github.com/evanalulu/The-Patisserie

Comment: In the Main.storyboard, I can see there are a lot of duplicate view controllers - all are called `ViewController` in one form or another. This is not going to work. It will create more confusion than to deliver necessary work. My advice would be to have two different classes defined in the code. One would be called `ProductsViewController` that shows all products. Other would be called `AddProductViewController`  that allows you to add a new product.

Comment: You should have EXACTLY 2 view controllers visible in the Main.storyboard, one for ProductsViewController and other for AddProductViewController. You MUST DELETE all other unused/test code from the Main.storyboard and then test it again.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make it far away a little bit from your `imageView` to make sure that there is no conflict between them, try it and give it a fixed width and height and it will work correctly, so all you need to do is to drag the image to the bottom till being separated from the button.

- Don't forget to give it the constraints (Trailing, Leading, Top & bottom)

Comment: could you remove the button and recreate it?

Comment: I made a new button with same function, but it didn't work. I think its the problem within the collection view cell.

Comment: I haven't added constraints to it yet

Comment: Kindly, Add constraints  like the updated answer

Comment: I tried adding constraints to all UI elements in the story board including the stuff inside the view cell, but it didn't work

Comment: So you gave all the elements in the cell constraints but still doesn't work??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233694/discussion-between-menaim-and-jennifer).